# Why are the array and the pointer to it stored in such different locations?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *titles[] = {"A Tale of Two Cities", "Wuthering Heights", "Don Quioxte", "Odyssey", "Moby Dick", "Hamlet", "Guilliver's Travels"};
    printf("The first letter of the titles: \n");
    printf("%c \n", *(titles[0]+21)); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites
    printf("%c \n", *titles[1]); //108 titles[1] = Wuthering Heights
    printf("%c \n", *titles[2]); //116 titles[2] = Don Quioxte
    printf("%c \n", *titles[3]); //124 titles[3] = Odyssey
    printf("%c \n", *titles[4]); //132 titles[4] = Moby Dick
    printf("%c \n", *titles[5]); //140 titles[5] = Hamlet
    printf("%c \n", *titles[6]); //141 titles[6] = Guilliver's Travels
    printf("The address (content of the pointer) of the first letter of the titles: \n");
    printf("%d \n", titles[0]); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites
    printf("%d \n", titles[1]); //108 titles[1] = Wuthering Heights
    printf("%d \n", titles[2]); //116 titles[2] = Don Quioxte
    printf("%d \n", titles[3]); //124 titles[3] = Odyssey
    printf("%d \n", titles[4]); //132 titles[4] = Moby Dick
    printf("%d \n", titles[5]); //140 titles[5] = Hamlet
    printf("%d \n", titles[6]); //141 titles[6] = Guilliver's Travels
    printf("The location of the pointer of titles: \n");
    printf("%d \n", &titles[0]); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites
    printf("%d \n", &titles[1]); //108 titles[1] = Wuthering Heights
    printf("%d \n", &titles[2]); //116 titles[2] = Don Quioxte
    printf("%d \n", &titles[3]); //124 titles[3] = Odyssey
    printf("%d \n", &titles[4]); //132 titles[4] = Moby Dick
    printf("%d \n", &titles[5]); //140 titles[5] = Hamlet
    printf("%d \n", &titles[6]); //141 titles[6] = Guilliver's Travels


    printf("%lu \n", sizeof(titles[0])); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
The first letter of the titles: 
W 
W 
D 
O 
M 
H 
G 
The address (content of the pointer) of the first letter of the titles: 
168152742 
168152763 
168152781 
168152793 
168152801 
168152811 
168152818 
The location of the pointer of titles: 
-440780528 
-440780520 
-440780512 
-440780504 
-440780496 
-440780488 
-440780480 
8
```

Comment: `titles` is on the stack. `titles[0]` is in the heap.  Don't print pointers with `%d`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: `titles[0]` is not in the heap.

Comment: The value of `titles[0]` is the address of a string literal.  It is indeed probably in the read only data section of the object file, but the details will differ by platform.  I loosely say "on the heap" to mean "not on the stack".  The point is, it is stored in a different location, so the addresses are different.

Comment: Data types exist, even for expressions. Respect them. [in fact:the crucial syntax element of C is `expression` ]

Answer (score 2):

You have discovered that the string literals are stored in the another memory area than the automatic variables. As yuo can see the compund literals are also placed in the memory where automatic variables are.

`sizeof(titles[0])` will only give you the size of the pointer (`titles` is the array of pointers). You need to use `strlen` function to get the size of the string referenced by the element of this array.

You need also use correct format specifiers as `%d` is incorrect if you want to print pointers.

https://godbolt.org/z/cPaa9W

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *titles[] = {(char[]){"A Tale of Two Cities"}, 
                      (char[]){"Wuthering Heights"}, 
                      (char[]){"Don Quioxte"}, 
                      (char[]){"Odyssey"}, 
                      (char[]){"Moby Dick"}, 
                      (char[]){"Hamlet"}, 
                      (char[]){"Guilliver's Travels"}};
    char *titles1[] = {"A Tale of Two Cities", "Wuthering Heights", "Don Quioxte", "Odyssey", "Moby Dick", "Hamlet", "Guilliver's Travels"};
    printf("The address (content of the pointer) of the first letter of the titles: \n");
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles[0]); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles[1]); //108 titles[1] = Wuthering Heights
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles[2]); //116 titles[2] = Don Quioxte
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles[3]); //124 titles[3] = Odyssey
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles[4]); //132 titles[4] = Moby Dick
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles[5]); //140 titles[5] = Hamlet
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles[6]); //141 titles[6] = Guilliver's Travels
    printf("The location of the pointer of titles: \n");
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles[0]); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles[1]); //108 titles[1] = Wuthering Heights
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles[2]); //116 titles[2] = Don Quioxte
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles[3]); //124 titles[3] = Odyssey
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles[4]); //132 titles[4] = Moby Dick
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles[5]); //140 titles[5] = Hamlet
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles[6]); //141 titles[6] = Guilliver's Travels

    printf("%zu %zu \n", sizeof(titles[0]), strlen(titles[0])); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites

    printf("\n\nThe address (content of the pointer) of the first letter of the titles1: \n");
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles1[0]); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles1[1]); //108 titles[1] = Wuthering Heights
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles1[2]); //116 titles[2] = Don Quioxte
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles1[3]); //124 titles[3] = Odyssey
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles1[4]); //132 titles[4] = Moby Dick
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles1[5]); //140 titles[5] = Hamlet
    printf("%p \n", (void *)titles1[6]); //141 titles[6] = Guilliver's Travels
    printf("The location of the pointer of titles: \n");
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles1[0]); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles1[1]); //108 titles[1] = Wuthering Heights
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles1[2]); //116 titles[2] = Don Quioxte
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles1[3]); //124 titles[3] = Odyssey
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles1[4]); //132 titles[4] = Moby Dick
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles1[5]); //140 titles[5] = Hamlet
    printf("%p \n", (void *)&titles1[6]); //141 titles[6] = Guilliver's Travels

    printf("%zu %zu \n", sizeof(titles1[0]), strlen(titles1[0])); //100 titles[0] = A Tale of Two Citites
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ANUPRIO Because `%p`, by it's pure definition, should match `void *` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays being pointed to are those of string literals. The array the pointers are is an automatic object (the memory of a variable defined inside a function).

It is common for compilers and program loaders to put string literals and automatic objects in different places. While compiling, the compiler gathers all the data for string literals and other constants and puts them in a particular section of the program. But it does not reserve any specific memory for the variable define inside functions, because these must be created and destroyed at run-time, as the functions are called. To manage this, most C implementations use a stack, which is a section of memory in which the used part grows and shrinks as functions are called and as they return.

It is common for the section for constants to be far away in memory from the stack. The addresses for the stack appear as negative numbers in part because of the way you have printed them. Printing addresses with `%d` is not correct. To print a pointer, convert it to `void *` and format it with `%p`. For example:

```
printf("%p \n", (void *) &titles[5]); //140 titles[5] = Hamlet
```

Comment: @ANUPRIO: The C standard defines formatting a pointer with `%p` in `printf` only for pointers of type `void *`. Therefore, to print any pointer in a way defined (albeit incompletely; the format used is implementation-dependent) by the C standard, it must be converted to `void *`. A reason behind this is that C implementations may implement different types of pointers in different ways. E.g., a `char *` may have a different size and representation than an `int *` or `struct foo *`. Converting them to `void *` produces a common representation to pass to `printf`.